# Requesting a POST from a react native app returns undefined Response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, request

I am very new to React Native and i was trying the integration of MongoDB cluster to an app. I created a server page with express() and MongodbClient. A GET request retrieves the result in the browser. But a POST request in the react native code results in an undefined Response

So my Server.js file looks as :

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var index = require("./routes/index");
var bookings = require("./routes/bookings");

var app = express();

var port = 3000;

app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log("Server running on port",port);
})

//views

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname,"views"));
app.set("view engine","ejs");
app.engine("html", require("ejs").renderFile);

//Body Parser MW

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))

//Routes

app.use("/",index);
app.use("/api",bookings);
```

The server/bookings.js file looks as:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient , assert = require("assert");
var uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@thecarcluster-3hqxd.mongodb.net/test?&w=majority";

console.log(uri);

router.get("/bookings",function(req,res,next){
    MongoClient.connect(uri,{connectTimeoutMS:60000})
    .then(client=>{
        const db = client.db('TheCar');
        const coll = db.collection("bookings");
        coll.find().toArray(function(err,bookings){
//            console.log("Data:"+ JSON.stringify(bookings));
            if(err){
                res.json(err);
            }
            res.send(JSON.stringify(bookings));
        });
        client.close();
    })
    .catch(err=>console.log(err));
});

router.post("/bookings",function(req,res,next){
    var bookings =req.body.data;
    if(!bookings.userName){
        res.status(400);
        res.json({
            error:"Bad data"
        });
    }
    else {
        MongoClient.connect(uri)
        .then(client=>{
            const db = client.db("TheCar");
            const coll = db.collection("bookings");
            coll.save(bookings,function(err,savedBooking){
                if(err){
                    res.send(err);
                }
                res.json(savedBooking);
            });
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err));
    }
});


module.exports = router;
```

The function that makes the POST request is as follows:

`````
export function bookCar(){
    return(dispatch,store)=>{
        const payload = {
            data:{
                username:"eman",
                pickUp:{
                    address :store().home.selectedAddress.selectedPickUp.address,
                    name : store().home.selectedAddress.selectedPickUp.name,
                    latitude: store().home.selectedAddress.selectedPickUp.location.latitude,
                    longitude: store().home.selectedAddress.selectedPickUp.location.longitude
                },
                dropOff:{
                    address :store().home.selectedAddress.selectedDropOff.address,
                    name : store().home.selectedAddress.selectedDropOff.name,
                    latitude: store().home.selectedAddress.selectedDropOff.location.latitude,
                    longitude: store().home.selectedAddress.selectedDropOff.location.longitude
                },
                fare: store().home.fare,
                status:"pending"                
            }
        }

        request.post("http://localhost:3000/api/bookings")
        .send(payload)
        .finish((err,res)=>{
            dispatch({
                type : BOOK_CAR,
                payload : res.body
            });
            console.log(err.message);
            console.log(res.status);
        });
    };
}
````

Also this has an import from a request.js file:

````
const request = require("superagent");
const defaultAjaxTimeout = 30000;
//const cookie = require("cookie");
request.Request.prototype.finish = function (callback) {
    // this replaces superagent's .end() function to include our custom error handling (see above)
    this.end((err,res)=>{
        callback(err,res);
    });
};

var requestWrapper = function(method) {
    // this is here so that we can append the .timeout call to all of our ajax requests with the default value.
    return function(url) {
        return request[method](url)
            .type("form")
            .timeout(defaultAjaxTimeout);
    };
};
export default {
    get: requestWrapper("get"),
    put: requestWrapper("put"),
    post: requestWrapper("post"),
    del: requestWrapper("del"),
};
````

As I am new, what i dont understand is, how does this function access the server/bookings.js that makes the connection to the Mongodb cluster. Is this why the response gets undefined.
`````

Answer (score 0):

If you do not automatically recognize your localhost address, you should check your device settings. If the actual device is utilized, it should be on the same IP.

**Android**

```
adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000
```

Comment: I have been using android emulator .. so wouldn’t this automatically identify the local host?

Comment: That's not true. The simulator doesn't know your communication medium. First, try to fit the port like my code